# Inserting check box data in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a form where a user tick on the checkbox then 1 will be stored in that column on MySQL table. If the user does not tick then 0 will be stored on that field in the database. One checkbox for one column. My HTML code is :

```
 Type ;<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="mentor" value="1" >Mentor</label>

  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="core" value="1" >Core</label>
```

and my PHP code is

```
 $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, $_POST['name']);
    $mentor;
    if (isset ($_POST['mentor']) == "1")
    {   
        $mentor = 1;

    } 
    else 
    {  
         $mentor = 0;
    }
    $core;
    if (isset ($_POST['core']) == "1")
    {   
        $core =1;

    } 
    else 
    {  
         $core =0;
    }
    $insert = $DBcon->query("INSERT into contributor(name,mentor,core) VALUES('$name','$mentor','$core')");
```

But I am getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????\"Exif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0\0\0\0\' at line 1"
this error when I press submit button

Comment: First things first. Don't concatenate your values into your SQL statement. Instead [bind them properly](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). That will solve some, if not all of the issue you are facing and keep you from suffering a sql injection attack.

Comment: Also change `isset ($_POST['core']) == "1"` to just `if isset ($_POST['core'])` same for mentor.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses single quotes to mean literals. That is, the $varname won't be interpreted to mean 0, it will mean $varname. Remove the single quotes and it should work.

`"INSERT into contributor(name,mentor,core) VALUES($name,$mentor,$core)"`
or
`'INSERT into contributor(name,mentor,core) VALUES('.$name.','.$mentor.','.$core.')'`

If this is for work, please read up on PHP PDO and the security it adds.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mixing *procedural* and *object-oriented* `mysqli_*` statements in your code. You should choose one or the other. Change your line here:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, $_POST['name']);
```

to this instead:

```
$DBCon->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

In addition, you will also want to remove the nested single quotes in your query statement:

```
$insert = $DBcon->query("INSERT into contributor(name,mentor,core) VALUES($name,$mentor,$core)");
```

**SECURITY IMPLICATIONS:**

I cannot go without saying (and without echoing the comments above), that you are leaving yourself open to *SQL Injection* attacks using this method. To ensure that you are protected, you should consider using the *prepared statements* offered by both the `mysqli_*` and `PDO_*` extensions.

Consider using the following safer alternative instead of the code you used above:

```
$DBCon = new \PDO('{dsn}', '{user}', '{pass}', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
]);

$mentor = (isset($_POST['mentor']) AND intval($_POST['mentor']) === 1) ? 1 : 0;
$core = (isset($_POST['core']) AND intval($_POST['core']) === 1) ? 1 : 0;

try {
    $stmt = $DBCon->prepare("INSERT INTO contributor(name,mentor,core) VALUES (:name,:mentor,:core)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mentor', $mentor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':core', $core, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    /* Cleanup (if you are finished interacting with the database) */
    $stmt = NULL;
    $DBCon = NULL;

} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    /* Handle Error Here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# as @War10ck mentioned, you're mixing Procedural-style with object oriented
$name = $DBCon->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

# You were comparing a boolean (isset) with "1". Since it's a checkbox, you an do this (or $_POST['mentor'] == "1" since that's your value on the form..)
$mentor = isset($_POST['mentor']) ? 1 : 0;
$core = isset($_POST['core']) ? 1 : 0;

# remove single quotes from your $paramaters
$insert = $DBcon->query("INSERT into contributor(name,mentor,core) VALUES($name, $mentor, $core)");
```

**Note you should use PDO prepared statements as others have mentioned**

```
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO contributor(name, mentor, core) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $name, $mentor, $core);

$insert = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: It's ideal to put the minimal, ideal version first.